Bitbucket Pipeline "docker: command not found"
After following the article "Run Docker commands in Bitbucket Pipelines" I came up with this sample pipeline I'm trying to build for a Python repository.
image: python:3.10-slim

pipelines:
  branches:
   '**':
     - step:
         name: Test Docker Commands
         runs-on:
            - 'self.hosted'
            - 'docker'
            - 'linux'
         services:
            - docker
         script:
            - docker version

definitions:
  services:
     docker:
        memory: 2048

But I get the following error:
bash: docker: command not found

I also tried to add the export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 but there were no improvements.
Is there something I'm missing or misunderstood?

Pipeline looks just fine. That should simply work. I'd suggest you review your self-hosted runners are properly mounting the docker engine in your container when the docker service is requested.

I found the solution to my problem. There were two main issues:

Runner System: The runner needed to be based on 'Linux Docker'.
Version Update: My runner was left at version 1.384. Updating it to the latest version (2.4.0) resolved the issue, and the docker commands became available.

Thank you, @N1ngu, for pointing me in the right direction!

Hi man, could give more explanation on how did you made those changes? I'm facing the same issue

Hi @nicowernli, the above-mentioned changes have been applied directly in BitBucket. You can check https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/runners/ if you use bitbucket too, otherwise I guess any other git-based repository has something similar.


 image: python:3.10-slim


There is no docker command inside python image. You have to install it inside the image, or use a docker:cli image.
See dind - "docker-in-docker" documentation, see docker.hub docker images and tags. See default bitbucket pipelines image documentation, see https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/default-image/ .

In Bitbucket Pipelines, Docker CLI binary is mounted by the "docker service" https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines/#How-it-works so you can use any image other than docker:dind

No, I disagreee. The docker service runs another container within the same docke network.  It creates a second container that can be reached on an network ip. Then, docker service runs docker daemn that listens for docker commands. Mounted are docker daemon certificates.  It is impossible to "mount" executables (reliably), like docker command, because of incompatibilities of standard libraries between containers. See services: in docker-compose.yml that works in similar fashion. Maybe services: in gitlab-ci.yml has better documentation.

This is no Docker Compose nor GitLab CI. If you read the docs I linked, this is how it works in the Bitbucket Pipelines world. The docker binary is statically linked so there are no library incompatibility issues.

Hi. You may be right, and I may be right. A statically linked executable still requires glibc to execute. -slim image alpine linux with musl, which executing a binary will fail with a message from linker with no such file or directory when trying to find ld.so . You linked to documentation, yes, but it's usage example. This is the reference https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/cache-and-service-container-definitions/#Services . There is one way to solve our difference - kindly prove that you are right.

@N1ngu Please post the output of  findmnt and mount from inside the container running with services:. I highly doubt docker executable is mounted and would find it highly confusing. If it is mounted, mount will show. Bottom line, I am always happy to be proven wrong, please do it. After rethinking, it is bash: printing the no such file or directory message. This messages proves this answer right. Please prove it wrong. Can you reproduce the error message from OP? The docker command is available in the default atlassian image, which is why it works in documentation.

sorry, it's been some years after I lost access to a bitbucket organization so I can't debug any of those proofs. But (1) I never used Atlassin's default image, that's not why it works in the docs; (2) I couldn't have reproduced OP error msg because the issue is due to their self-hosted runners, that would never happen in mine or cloud runners (3) OP error message does not proof this answer right; (4) yes, docker binary being mounted felt odd when I started but it worked, shared runners wouldn't show how the job spawned but pipes do log the --mount=.../docker:...bin/docker option!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
